Conditional Layouts based on Parameter
I would like my .razor page to have the Default Layout (MainLayout) unless the LayoutType parameter is == "Tab"  I am always getting the TabLayout.  The default layout is MainLayout.
@page "/WasteNum/{LayoutType}"

@if (LayoutType == "Tab")
{
    @layout TabLayout 
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string LayoutType { get; set; } = "Main";
}


You could implement logic to use layout dynamically in App.razor 's "Router".Based on your needs you could modify App.razor as following
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
<Router ...
...
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="GetLayoutType()" />
...

        <LayoutView Layout="GetLayoutType()">
...
</Router>


@code {

    private Type GetLayoutType()
    {
        if (_navigationManager.Uri.EndsWith("Tab"))
        {
            return typeof(TabLayout);
        }
        else
        {
            return typeof(MainLayout);
        }
    }
}


Qiang, thank you very much for your excellent idea.  I had to modify your code just slightly to make it work for me.  I posted my solution as a reference below.

To implement conditional layouts based on the LayoutType parameter, you could set the layout programmatically within the OnInitialized lifecycle method or use logic that does not rely on the @layout directive directly inside the Razor page.
    @page "/WasteNum/{LayoutType}"

@layout MainLayout

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string LayoutType { get; set; } = "Main";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (LayoutType == "Tab")
        {
            Layout = typeof(TabLayout);
        }
        else
        {
            Layout = typeof(MainLayout);
        }
    }
}


Hi Arnav, I am getting the following error with your code.
Error (active) CS0118 'MudBlazorTraining.Components.Layout' is a namespace but is used like a variable

It is possible that the variable Layout is clashing with something already defined in your code or namespace. In Blazor, the Layout property is defined within the framework itself. If you also have a namespace or class named Layout in your project, there could be a naming conflict.
Make sure TabLayout and MainLayout are properly defined components or layouts in your project.

I changed my Layout Folder to Layouts.  Note, when you create a WebApp Project Layout is the name given to that folder by Visual Studio.
I now get the following error.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) CS0103 The name 'Layout' does not exist in the current context MudBlazorTraining

Qiang thank you very much for the brilliant idea.  Below is the actual code that worked in my solution.
    @using MudBlazorTraining.Components.Layouts
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="GetLayoutType()" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

@code {

    private Type GetLayoutType()
    {
        if (Navigation.Uri.EndsWith("Tab"))
        {
            return typeof(TabLayout);
        }
        else
        {
            return typeof(MainLayout);
        }
    }
}

